# Micronaut MockBean/Replaces not working for pojo in controller test using @MicronautTest

Tags: junit5, micronaut

I am using Micronaut framework. I am writing junit for following controller. -

```
class Controller {
    Client client;

    List<Object> handleEvent(Object event) {
        try {
            client.handle(event);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            throw new Exception()
        }
    }

}
```

I want to mock client object. I tried with both @MockBean annotation as well as @Replaces annotation. But no luck.

Client is injected from a factory -

```
@Factory
class ClientFactory {
    @Singleton
    @Named("client_name")
    Client getClient() {
        return new Client();
    }
}
```

I tried following annotations in test -

```
@Inject 
Client client;

@MockBean(bean = Client.class, named = "client_name")
Client getClient() {
    return Mockito.mock(Client.class);
}
```

It gives error - **"Failed to inject value for parameter client_name of class registrar. No bean of type exists for the given qualifier @Named(client_name)"** Registrar is another class that also has injected client with same name. Not sure why it is coming into picture of controller.

I am little puzzled by these errors. I also tried @Replaces annotation, like this -

```
@Replaces(value = Client.class, named = "client_name)
Client getClient() {
    return Mockito.mock(Client.class);
}
```

But no luck. Could someone guide what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You `Factory` implementation suggests that your bean definition is of actual injected class `new Client()`.

***Micronaut* fails to replace / inject class defined beans** and you will have to introduce an intermediary interface providing your bean exposed API then mock the latter:

Define your common type interface:

```java
interface Client {

    void handleEvent(Object event);

}
```

Provide the default `Client` implementation (note that you can supply factory provider with `Primary` annotation so it gets picked as default one when more than one injectable type is present):

```java
public class DefaultClient {

    public void handleEvent(Object event) {
        // your default implementation goes here
    }

}
```

Your `Factory` should inject the default concrete implementation:

```java
@Factory
public class ClientFactory {
    
    @Singleton
    @Named("client_name")
    public Client getClient() {
        return new DefaultClient();
    }
}
```

You controller implementation remain unchanged and does not have to care about implementation details:

```java
class Controller {

    Client client; // the interface is injected in here

    List<Object> handleEvent(Object event) {
        try {
            client.handle(event);
        } catch (Exception E) {
            throw new Exception()
        }
    }

}
```

Your test bean then can have the custom implementation replacing the default one:

```
@MockBean(DefaultClient.class)
Client client() {
    return Mockito.mock(Client.class);
}
```

> As a general advice, you should better program to interface and only inject these while annotating your concrete implementations for bean introspection.